# How to locate a cell value that ends in "net" and delete row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this procedure that is looking for any cell in Col D where the value ends in "net" then it will delete the entire row/rows. But it does not delete all of the rows where the value ends in "net". I am out of ideas.

```
Sub DeleteRows_net()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Range("D4:D2700")

If InStr(1, rng.Value, "net") > 0 Then
rng.EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It is so common mistake... When you loop to delete you have to start from last element taking direction to first.  Change looping into:

```
Dim i%
For i=2700 to 4 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, "D").Value, "net") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

By the way... Do not forget to place `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` somewhere before end of procedure!

Comment: Faster than a Ferrari F12. Your solution worked perfect. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome... You could mark it as solved not to bother other helpful people.

Comment: One slight addition I am trying to overcome. I added a sub string to search for both "net" and "com" and it is not working. If InStr(1, Cells(i, "D").Value, "net", "com") > 0 Then

Comment: Change into: `If InStr(1, Cells(i, "D").Value, "net") > 0 Or InStr(1, Cells(i, "D").Value, "com") > 0 Then`